# The action of a topological group on the function space is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, group-actions, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Sorry for my bad english.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces, and $G$ a topological group, let $\theta : G \times X \to X$ be a continuous action of $G$ on $X$. We defined the action of $G$ on the space of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ with compact open topology, $\phi : G \times \mathcal{C} (X,Y) \to \mathcal{C} (X,Y)$, where $[\phi (g,f)](x) = f(g^{-1} x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Now, I have to prove that if $G$ is locally compact then $\phi$ is a continuous action.

I have already seen that $\phi$ is well defined and that $\phi$ is an action, but I can not prove that $\phi$ is continuous. I found in a book the case when $G = X$ and it say it follows from the Theorem that said that $\phi$ is continuous iff the function $\phi *: (G \times \mathcal{C} (X,Y)) \times X \to Y$ is continuous, where $\phi * ((g,f),x) = [\phi (g,f)] (x) = f(g^{-1} x)$, but I can't see how it follows.

What I wanted to do, is use the Theorem that said: The continuity of an action $\phi : G \times \mathcal{C} (X,Y) \to \mathcal{C} (X,Y)$ of a topological group $G$ with identity $e$ on a space $\mathcal{C} (X,Y)$ is equivalent to the continuity of $\phi$ at the points of the set $\lbrace e \rbrace \times \mathcal{C} (X,Y) \subset G \times \mathcal{C} (X,Y)$. So I only need to see that if $f \in \mathcal{C} (X,Y)$ then for every neighborhood $(K,U)$ of $f$, in compact open topology, there exist neighborhoods $O$ of $e \in G$ and $(K',U')$ of $f$ such that $\phi (O \times (K',U')) \subset (K,U)$, but I don't know how to use the hypothesis of G locally compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity I assume that the group $G$ is Hausdorff. Since $f\in (K,U)$, we have $K\subset f^{-1}(U)$. Since $\theta$ is a continuous action, for each $x\in K$ there exist open neighborhood $U_x$ of $X$ and a symmetric compact neighborhood $O_x$ of $e$ such that $\theta (O_x\times U_x)\subset f^{-1}(U)$. A family $\{U_x:x\in K\}$ is an open cover of a compact set $K$. Thus there exists a finite subset $F$ of $K$ such that $\{U_x:x\in F\}$ is an open cover of $K$. Then $O=\bigcap\{O_x:x\in F\}$ is a symmetric compact neighborhood of $e$ such that $K’=\theta(O\cdot K)\subset f^{-1}(U)$. Since the map $\theta$ is continuous, the set $K’$ is compact. Thus $f\in (K’,U)$. We claim that $\phi (O \times (K',U')) \subset (K,U)$. Indeed, let $f’\in\phi(O\times (K’,U))$ be any function and $x\in K$ be any point. Then $f’(x)=f’’(g^{-1}x)$ for some $g\in O$ and $f’’\in (K’,U)$. But $g^{-1}x\in O^{-1}x=Ox\subset O\cdot K=K’$, so $f’(x)\in f’’(K’)\subset U$. Thus $f'\in (K,U)$.